# Removing the redundant feature from classification dataset ( make_classification )

Tags: scikit-learn, statistics, data-science, correlation

In the make_classification method,

`X,y = make_classification(n_samples=10, n_features=8, n_informative=7, n_redundant=1, n_repeated=0 , n_classes=2,random_state=6)`

> **Docstring about *n_redundant*:** The number of redundant features. These features are generated as
> random linear combinations of the informative features.

> **Docstring about *n_repeated*:** The number of duplicated features, drawn randomly from the informative

1. n_repeated features are picked easily as they are highly correlated with informative features.
2. The docstring for repeated and redundant features indicates that both are drawn from informative features.

My question is: how redundant features can be removed/highlighted, what are their characteristics.

Attached is the correlation heatmap among all the features, Which feature in the image is redundant.

Please help.[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s about statistics, not programming. It belongs on [stats.se] instead of here.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I actually look for sklearn point of view how redundant data can be removed from the fake data generation method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To check how many independent columns use `np.linalg.matrix_rank(X)`
2. To find indices of linearly independent rows of matrix X use `sympy.Matrix(X).rref()`

**DEMO**

Generate dataset and check number of independent columns (matrix rank):

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sympy import Matrix

X, _ = make_classification(
    n_samples=10, n_features=8, n_redundant=2,random_state=6
)
np.linalg.matrix_rank(X, tol=1e-3)
# 6
```

Find indices of linearly independent columns:

```py
_, inds = Matrix(X).rref(iszerofunc=lambda x: abs(x)<1e-3)
inds
#(0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7)
```

Remove dependent columns and check matrix rank (num of independent columns):

```py
#linearly independent
X_independent = X[:,inds]
assert np.linalg.matrix_rank(X_independent, tol=1e-3) == X_independent.shape[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I have connected the question, the above solution, it always shows the column with all zero in the end, ( I tried tweaking the data). not specific to the index of the redundant features. or am I missing any catch here.

Comment: Thanks. yes agree, it shows zero rows as per the redundant features, however, it is not highlighting the index of the redundant feature( always showing zero at the end of the matrix). There may be the case where feature other than the last indexed could be redundant.. hope I am able to explain my point.

Comment: @SantoshKumar Please see updated. R matrix in QR decomposition only tells the rank of the matrix, and not which particular columns are linearly dependent, as you correctly pointed out. If one relies on QR decomposition, he must [manually](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748500/how-to-find-linearly-independent-columns-in-a-matrix)  find columns responsible for all zeros row at the end of R matrix.